# How to read a matrix from a text in Matlab

Tags: matlab, file-io

I recently ran into this the other day, I'm not that good of a programmer, and the teacher asked us to make a program that reads a square matrix from a txt. and then use the information to solve it. I've been wondering how to do the first part of this program as I already figured it out how to solve the matrix, but I just don't know how to do the scanning of the text. Just so you guys can understand me, this is how the text would look like:

4

1 2 3 8

7 4 1 2

1 2 1 2

3 4 5 6

So as you can see, it has to read the first number and store it in a variable so the program knows the size of the matrix and then read the matrix and store it in an array or so I think.

Any help would be apreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please note that tags are not keywords. That is, stuffing the tag list full of the same words you use in your question and question title does not help people to find your question. Tags stand alone, meaning tagging with `read` and `text`  does not mean that you are trying to read lines from a text file. Please select tags with care.

Comment: This sounds like a C/C++ problem cast in MATLAB.

Answer (score 0):

```
D = importdata('file.txt');
rows = D(1);
cols = (numel(D)-1)/rows;
D = reshape(D(2:end),[cols rows])';
```

(best MATLAB solution would be to remove the number of rows in the beginning. Then `importdata` would be sufficient)

Answer (score 0):

suppose `file.txt` is

> 1 2 3 8
>
> 7 4 1 2
>
> 1 2 1 2
>
> 3 4 5 6

The command is

> load  file.txt

and then you get a variable **file**

the size of **file** is **[4,4]**.